# Not able to import com.adobe.cq.social.srp.utilities.api.SocialResourceUtilities package in AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

Is any one can give me the dependency to add in global and core pom , so that i can  use this interface in my jave class

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.cq.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-social-srp-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.35</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

To find the dependency, go to `http://<domain>:<port>/system/console/depfinder` , and search with the package/class name. If the package is exported by bundles already present in the instance, the interface will display the maven dependency to be used.

The above dependency is from 6.3 version, repeat the steps above to find the dependency version available on 6.2